# How to detect that my select form have been change by ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two form input ( text and select form ).
The select form change by ajax success when user search the employee data.
Now, i want the other jquery function that can automatically detect when the select form have been change by ajax success and retrieve the new value of select form to use by other function to make new data in my input text.

my Search Employee Function

```
    function search_personal_result(formObj, urlres, responseDIV, disable_data, modal_class,result_data)
{
    disable_data=disable_data||false;
    modal_class=modal_class||false;
    result_data=result_data||false;
    var loading = '<p>Loading ...</p>';
        $.ajax({
        url: site_url+'/'+urlres,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(responseDIV).html(loading);
        }, 
        data: $(formObj).serialize(), 
        type: "post", 
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response){
            //proceed data result here
            if(result_data==false){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                    if(result_data==false){
                        for(var j in value){
                            //My SELECT Form Changed here
                            $('#VCIDSBU').val('MY NEW VALUE');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Terjadi kesalahan!");
        },
    });
}
```

If the user search the employee data using search_personal_result, my select form have been successfully changes.

Now that i need is, how to make the other jQuery function that can detect that my SELECT Form have been changed by search_personal_result

I have try using

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_create_sp').on('change','SELECT#my_select_id',function(){
            alert('it changes');
    });
})
```

It can only detect when the user manually change the select form. but not working when the select form changed by search_personal_result

Thanks for all expert here

Comment: If you share the code for your ajax call, you can get a more precise answer. Without that I can only say this - get "success" callback to pass the new value to that other function and trigger it.

Comment: Thanks your advice, i have add some code to my question

Comment: After `$('#VCIDSBU').val('MY NEW VALUE');` add a new line: `alert('it changes')`

Answer (score 1):

You could always do some sort of console.log("Success"); Function based on if it sent or not.